# No output to the monitor

Tags: vga

The computer's mobo is kinda old but I don't think it should matter. 
I have tried connecting the computer with DVI, VGA, built in VGA cables, still no signal. But the computer was working at my friend's house. I have just removed the HDD and put mine it.
Help?

Comment: ??  Let me understand.  The computer worked fine at your friend's house.  You unplugged everything, lugged it to your house, plugged everything in to use it, and you have no video output?  Otherwise, all the lights seem to indicate that it is working properly?  The HDD activity light flashes as if it's booting normally, fans are spinning up, Optical drive light comes on at boot, etc?  Or is it possible that you accidentally brushed something (Ram, power connection, etc) when you were inside the computer pulling out the old drive?

Comment: I haven't told you the whole story. His HDD was IDE, my HDD is SATA. It may not be detecting HDD properly because HDD light doesn't blink (though the fans work fine).

Comment: Even with the difference between the types of drives, if the drive is connected to the motherboard and the power supply, if the video adapter not working properly, the HDD light would flash as it was accessed.  It might not keep on flashing as if it was loading an OS, but the *attempt* to load an OS would happen, and the light would flash.  The light on the optical drive would come on as well, fans would spin up, etc.  All that would happen if the computer was booting without a display.  Otherwise, if none of that is happening (fans, lights, etc) then the problem is more than the display.

Answer (score 0):

Hard drive or no hard drive, you should see something on the display unless the computer isn't passing POST, or something is wrong with the video adapter or anything along the signal path. Try a different monitor and cable. If you still see no video, try a different video card. If you still get nothing, remove all removable parts except the processor/fan, one stick of memory and the video card. If you still see nothing, swap DIMMs. If still nothing, then it is probably the motherboard.

Comment: Why don't you just remove RAM and use a eraser to clean the head and replace it. it may work for you.

Comment: @tiki: A)Why would you jump right to the RAM if you don't even know it is the problem? There are a number of things that can cause this, my method narrows down the bad component in a logical manner. Choosing one option at random is a shotgun method of diagnostics. B)Why would you suggest a potentially damaging solution? Some erasers might be safe, but many contain acids that could damage the RAM. Isopropyl alcohol with q-tips would be safer. Again, this would only work if the RAM is bad, you need to narrow that down first, hence my answer. Cleaning RAM will do nothing for a bad monitor cable.